# SQL server 2005 backup statistic

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, backup

I'd like to share with you this simple snippet (answering my own question) and I'm also curious how do you control your SQL server backups.

Answer (score 6):

One of the slickest ways I've seen to control backups is Ola Hallengren's free maintenance script solution:

http://ola.hallengren.com/

It's installed as a series of stored procs in Master that do all kinds of nifty utility tasks.  It'll automatically handle newly added databases, leverages third party backup compression tools, and does index rebuilds/defrags too.

Answer (score 1):

This query draws from msdb backup history and shows volumes and numbers aggregated weekly. It should be straightforward to modify it to fit your specific needs.

```
;with backups as (
 select 
      bs.*
    , backupTarget = case 
          when bs.type = 'D' then 'FULL'
          when bs.type = 'I' then 'DIFF'
          when bs.type = 'L' then 'LOG'
          else 'OTHER'
          end
    , groupDate = dateadd(week, DATEDIFF(WEEK, '2000-01-01', bs.backup_start_date), '2000-01-01')
 from msdb.dbo.backupset bs
)
select 
 groupDate
 , groupWeek  = cast(year(groupDate) + DATEPART(week, groupDate) / 100.0 as decimal(8, 2))
 , [Full MB]  = cast(sum( case backupTarget when 'FULL' then backup_size else 0 end ) / 1024 / 1024 as int)
 , [Diff MB]  = cast(sum( case backupTarget when 'DIFF' then backup_size else 0 end ) / 1024 / 1024 as int)
 , [Log MB]   = cast(sum( case backupTarget when 'LOG' then backup_size else 0 end ) / 1024 / 1024 as int)
 , [Other MB] = cast(sum( case backupTarget when 'OTHER' then backup_size else 0 end ) / 1024 / 1024 as int)            
 , [Full #]   = sum( case backupTarget when 'FULL' then 1 else 0 end )
 , [Diff #]   = sum( case backupTarget when 'DIFF' then 1 else 0 end ) 
 , [Log #]    = sum( case backupTarget when 'LOG' then 1 else 0 end ) 
 , [Other #]  = sum( case backupTarget when 'OTHER' then 1 else 0 end )  
 , [Full s]   = sum( case backupTarget when 'FULL' then DATEDIFF(s, backup_start_date, backup_finish_date) else 0 end ) 
 , [Diff s]   = sum( case backupTarget when 'DIFF' then DATEDIFF(s, backup_start_date, backup_finish_date) else 0 end ) 
 , [Log s]    = sum( case backupTarget when 'LOG' then DATEDIFF(s, backup_start_date, backup_finish_date) else 0 end ) 
 , [Other s]  = sum( case backupTarget when 'OTHER' then DATEDIFF(s, backup_start_date, backup_finish_date) else 0 end )
 from backups 
group by 
    groupDate
order by 1 desc
```